# Swapping Rows in Database tables By using the primary Key In php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rows, swap

In my application i want to swap rows in database.

That means , my table has following strusure,

```
Column     Type             Null    Default     Comments

intid         int(11)           No           
intuserid         int(11)           No           
vchimagename      varchar(50)   No
```

Here intid is primary key.

When i using this function for wsapping ,

```
function row_swap($table, $id1, $id2)
{
    if (!mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET intid='$id1' where intid='$id2'"))
    {
        echo mysql_error() ;
        exit ;
    }
    if (!mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET intid='$id2' where intid='$id1'"))
    {
        echo mysql_error() ;
        exit ;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Calling function ,

```
row_swap('tblupload', 7, 8) ;
```

Then it displays error,

```
Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So how can i swap rows by using thier primary key?

If it is possible?

Comment: No! Don't do it. It's not a good idea ever to change your primary key values, so don't get into the habit. It will break any relationships to that table from other related tables.

Comment: @Mark Baker,then how can i swap the rows?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to 'swap' rows?

Comment: Update other fields of those rows and do not try to change your `initid` as `PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 0):

```
function row_swap($table, $id1, $id2)
{
    if (!mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET intid='999999' where intid='$id2'"))
    {
        echo mysql_error() ;
        exit ;
    }
    if (!mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET intid='$id2' where intid='$id1'"))
    {
        echo mysql_error() ;
        exit ;
    }
    if (!mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET intid='$id1' where intid='999999'"))
    {
        echo mysql_error() ;
        exit ;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

You should use temporary id (999999)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Primary key is never a good coding practice.

The error you are getting is because the primary key

- cannot have duplicate record (Means it should be unique)
- cannot be left NULL

suppose your variables were set as
id1 = 1
id2 = 2

Now what you did in the first query is that you swapped the id2 with id1

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET intid='$id1' where intid='$id2'")
```

in the database now the fields are updated as
id1 = 2
id2 = 2

this violates the rule of the primary key. so you got an error

> Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'

The solution is to take a dummy value as temp and then swap the values. You might have done this if you made the swap two numbers problem (in school or while learning any programming language).

you take a temp variable and swap number A and B as

```
temp = A;
A = B;
B = Temp;
```

The solution provided by @NobitaZZ is correct unless and until your intid value goes to the mark of 999999. choose a value which you know wont interfere with your logic.